# Deleted UILabel in Interface Builder still shows up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface

I am having a bug that has got me stumped. I created a label a short while ago that was just a placeholder to be replaced in the future. Finally, I get to replacing it with a button, so I delete the UILabel and put a UIButton in its place (keep in mind this is all in Interface Builder). When I run the program in the simulator, the new button isn't there and instead there is the old label which has been deleted. I have searched my whole program and I have no reference to this label, it is completely out of my program, yet it still appears in IB and my new button does not. I have tried Cleaning the program and quitting Xcode several times to no avail. If anybody knows of or has faced a similar problem I would love to hear your solution.

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems in your case NIBs are cached in Simulator, delete your app from inside Simulator and rebuild/reinstall then it shall be fine.

Comment: Another thing to try is to manually trash the *build* folder inside your project folder in the Finder.  This is the *" Nuke it from low orbit; it's the only way to be sure."* option.

Answer (score 1):

With xcode 3 I would have guessed that you did not save the xib file within Interface Buidler.

Still in xcode 4 I sometimes get the impression that not all changes come to effect for whatever reason. As if one or two source files do not get compiled at all.

Then I close xcode, save everything and start over again.

Comment: Thanks Hermann, I would usually think the same thing but I have tried saving and quitting several times and it still does not work. This is one of the weirder things that I've seen because the Label is not referenced anywhere in the program at this point, yet it still appears...